Arduino Cloud Editor doesn't work on ChromeOS
https://www.arduino.cc updated their web-based IDE this week, and now the IDE does not recognize my Pitsco PRIZM Robotic controllers on ChromeOS. I cannot find a generic "Board" device to use with the IDE.
Is there a way to get the new web-based Arduino IDE on ChromeOS to work with a clone such as PRIZM?

UPDATE May 25:
The Arduino Cloud developers have now restored support for uploading to 3rd party derivatives of the officially supported boards from Arduino Cloud Editor on ChromeOS machines.
So the workarounds I described in my prior answer are no longer required and you can now use these derivative boards with Cloud Editor by simply selecting the equivalent official board from the "Select a device type" dialog.

Original answer:
Arduino officially supports uploading to a specific list of official boards from Arduino Cloud Editor on ChromeOS machines: Boards compatible with the Cloud Editor - Cloud Editor on Chromebook
Up until recently, there was also incidental support for ChromeOS users to upload to 3rd party compatibles and derivatives of those official boards boards (such as your "Pitsco PRIZM Robotic Controller") that use a general purpose USB to serial bridge chip (e.g., FTDI FT232R, Silicon Labs CP2102, WCH CH340).
That incidental support for these 3rd party boards was lost during a recent rewrite of Cloud Editor.
At this time, I can suggest some possible solutions for affected users:

Use Cloud Editor on a Linux, macOS or Windows machine (the issue is specific to ChromeOS machines).
Use one of the officially supported Arduino boards (I understand this option is less reasonable in the case where the supported boards are not a drop-in hardware replacement, as is the case with @Ray Salemi's "PRIZM Robotic Controller", but wanted to mention it for the benefit of others who have a clone-ish derivative board).

The impact on ChromeOS users only emerged a matter of days before the time I write this answer so there is a chance the situation will evolve. If other options become known or available, I'll make an update as appropriate so stay tuned.

Thank you for the detailed answer!

One note: the cloud editor cannot find the PRIZM on a Mac using Chrome.    The MacOS IDE  (and Windows IDE) still support the PRIZM.


cloud editor cannot find the PRIZM on a Mac

I'm confident the problem has a different cause than the problem you experienced on the ChromeOS machine. So the new problem should be addressed separately.
You can make a new question here on SE if you like. However, I personally don't have an answer on hand as was the case with the ChromeOS question. In this case where a significant back and forth between user and support technician may be required, Arduino Forum might be a better platform. If you make a post over there I'll be sure to see it and help as I can.
